# Syntax Error for Ruby on Rails "(" unexpected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

**rails -v**

Activating the command above results in:

**bin/rails: 7: bin/rails: Syntax error: "(" unexpected**

My rails in engine seems to not be running correctly, and is not responding.

It tells about syntax error when I try to call rails -v, or rails db:create or something like that.

**rails s** returns the same error

Here is the rest of the .gemspec file I used:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

$:.push File.expand_path('lib', __dir__)

# Maintain your gem's version:
require 'vulnerabilities/version'

# Describe your gem and declare its dependencies:
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = 'vulnerabilities'
  s.version     = Vulnerabilities::VERSION
  s.authors     = ['Evgeny Karpenko']
  s.email       = ['e.karpenko@isoit.ru']
  s.homepage    = 'https://new.docshell.ru'
  s.summary     = 'Vulnerabilities Plugin for Docshell4'
  s.description = 'VulnerabilitiesPlugin for Docshell4'
  s.license     = 'proprietary'

  s.files = Dir['{app,config,db,lib}/**/*', 'MIT-LICENSE', 'Rakefile', 'README.md']

  s.add_dependency 'rails', '~> 5.1.6', '>= 5.1.6.1'

  s.add_dependency 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.7'
  s.add_dependency 'kaminari', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.1'
  s.add_dependency 'pg', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.2'
  s.add_dependency 'swagger-blocks', '~> 2.0.2'
  s.add_dependency 'rest-client', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.2'

  s.add_development_dependency 'annotate'
  s.add_development_dependency 'database_cleaner'
  s.add_development_dependency 'factory_bot_rails'
  s.add_development_dependency 'faker'
  s.add_development_dependency 'rspec'
  s.add_development_dependency 'rspec-instrumentation-matcher'
  s.add_development_dependency 'rspec-rails'
  s.add_development_dependency 'shoulda-matchers'
end
```

here is the bin/rails file, which can not run File.expand_path

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# This command will automatically be run when you run "rails" with Rails gems
# installed from the root of your application.

ENGINE_ROOT = File.expand_path('..', __dir__)
ENGINE_PATH = File.expand_path('../lib/vulnerabilities/engine', __dir__)
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../spec/dummy/config/application', __dir__)

# Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../Gemfile', __dir__)
require 'bundler/setup' if File.exist?(ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'])

require 'rails/all'
require 'rails/engine/commands'
```

Comment: Run `rails server` to see the full stack trace and you might be able to find the syntax error

Comment: Is that the full error? Just one line? Nothing more in the backtrace?

Comment: And to be clear, is it complaining about line 7: `ENGINE_ROOT = File.expand_path('..', __dir__)` ? I don't see anything wrong with that line, but what happens if you comment it out?

Comment: Tom Lord, it's the only error, one string.

If I comment it - the error appears on next line. The reason is my rails broken there.

Answer (score 3):

The reason was in this line:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
```

after removing it - rails starts to work properly

this line appeared due to RuboCop intervention